# Entitlements Do Not Match: Provisioning Profile Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

Using Xcode, I'm trying to upload my archive to the App Store and I'm getting:

> ERROR ITMS-90163: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile 'aps-environment' in 'Payload/App Name.app/App Name'."

Then below is gives additional detail, identifying:

> The bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile: 'com.apple.security.application-groups' in Payload/App Name.app/App Name'."

With this version I have added a 'today notification widget', iMessage stickers, and 3D Touch support. I think the notification data sharing (app-group) has something to do with my problem. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Which Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this by resetting the code signing (uncheck it, wait 10 seconds, check it again):

[image]